# Do we need the [color] tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, tags

While reviewing suggested edits, I came across [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32319) for the [color](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) tag's tag wiki. After looking further into the tag, I found that it did not have a tag wiki beforehand, and there are only three questions that are using it currently. Looking at those questions this tag seems pretty unnecessary in the first place. In fact, the third question was the question where this tag was created.

Here are the three questions:

- [The Camouflage Color Changing Chameleon Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84937/the-camouflage-color-changing-chameleon-challenge)
- [Use 16 colors while writing Hey! 4 times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85047/use-16-colors-while-writing-hey-4-times)
- [From Rgb to Cmyk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84066/from-rgb-to-cmyk)

[Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/color/info) is  the link to the tag wiki for [color](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color).

Comment: Actually I've been meaning to add and consistently apply this tag for months (but didn't get around to it). We definitely have more than 3 challenges about colour spaces and colour conversion, so I think it would be useful. (I probably wouldn't use for things like the second challenge you linked though.)

Comment: It's probably not the greatest of tags, but I could see it fitting on a good 20-25 challenges. Plus it's not doing any harm. I see no reason to get rid of it.